Is there a workaround for using a variable for the PATH declaration in a systemd .path unit file?
I've consulted the documentation in regards to systemd.path files: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.path.html and specifically within the documentation they list:

PathExists=, PathExistsGlob=, PathChanged=, PathModified=,
DirectoryNotEmpty=
...
The arguments of these directives must be absolute file system paths.

So I guess I'm looking for kind of a work-around if possible for defining the PathModified statement using a variable instead of an absolute path. I'm in actuality trying to create a systemd .path unit file template file where the PATH variable can be dynamically assigned because it's a template. Although I'm very aware the code below causes an error, I'm attempting something like this:
    # /etc/systemd/system/srv-watch@.path
    [Path]
    EnvironmentFile=/etc/systemd/system/traefik.env
    PathModified="${TRAEFIK_PATH}"
    Unit="srv-watcher@%i.service"
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target

   # /etc/systemd/system/traefik.env
   TRAEFIK_PATH=/usr/bin/traefik
   UPGRADE_PATH=/root/bin/upgrade_traefik.sh

I'm not exactly sure if there is a systemd way to construct these system .path template files (filename@.path), however it just seems odd to me since the .service and .timer files definitely possess "template ability".  I suppose I could use another templating tool such as ansible/jinja2 that would "dynamically" create the systemd .path files containing a "fixed" or "absolute" path for the PathModified declaration, however it would be really nice to avoid another tool or method if possible.

If you are using templates, your template installation tool should fix the path.  While ansible et al can do it, there are simpler things -- like bash itself.  Or (not that I'd recommend it), m4 which is frequently installed by default.  If you need an example using simpler tools, comment and I'll write up an answer if someone doesn't beat me to it.

I don't know anything about m4, however just a suggestion on tools I should maybe explore would be great. I'm attempting to setup these systemd unit files during provisioning of VMs and proxmox containers if that helps.
